# Bot does not send photos after about two weeks (unless I send him them again)

Tags: telegram-bot

So I've made a chat bot just to have fun with friends. It basically sends stickers or photos when triggered by some words. The issue I'm experiencing is that after about two weeks it will no longer send photos unless I send him again.

More specifically: I have a set of pictures already stored on Telegram cloud and bot does send them using their file id. The first time I've tested it I realised I had to send him all those pictures so that he "had access" to a private file, and then it worked fine.
Some days ago I noticed it didn't send those pictures anymore, like I never sent him, and it starded to work again as I re-forwarded them. It's like access to file ids expire after a certain time. Is there a way to prevent this and let the bot keep access to those file ids "forever"?

Comment: You should check what the response is when the message is sent.

Comment: The response was "file id not found", just like it had never received those photos. However this issue hasn't showed up again so far.